# Bash script Unexpected error EOF

Tags: linux, bash

I'm getting an error with my script for the last line of the file and I'm not sure why:

```
./sampledata: line 55: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Example Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

temptime=$(date +"%H:%M")

usercount=0
while word in userfile
{ usercount=$usercount+1 }


counter=0
usercount=$usercount/2 #format

echo -n $temptime " |" >> numusersfile

while $counter -le $usercount
{
    echo -n "*" >> numusersfile
    counter=$counter+1
}
echo "" >> numusersfile
```

Am I doing my loops correctly? Or is there something wrong with how I'm writing to the file? I'm kinda stumped on this right now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while loops in bash should be like this:

```
while [ $counter -le $usercount ]
do
    echo -n "*" >> numusersfile
    counter=$counter+1
done
```

Mind the spaces around `[` and `]` and that brackets are replaced with `do` and `done`

Comment: If one follows [McConnell's practice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3906401/2908724), bring the `do` up after the test, like: `while [ $counter -le $usercount ]; do`

Comment: This fixes the EOF error but I'm now left with other errors, I'll update the code